# How to align multiple components together in a single view?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 same for vuetify. I have a dashboard I have changed the old components to vuetify components and all but the problem comes here. I have 4 components in a single view called `AppDashboard.vue`. Somehow these components don't align together height wise? I have attached the screenshot:

What would be the most ideal way to do so. Considering the latest vue3 and vuetify3

[image]

The following is my `AppDashboard.vue`

```
<template>
    <v-main>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col>
                        <DashboardWalletInfo ref="dashboardWallets" :wallets="allwallets" @update-allwallets="updateAllWallets"/>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col>
                        <AppStrategy/>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col>
                        <AppExport v-bind:swapHistory="recentSwaps" v-on:get-swap-history="handleGetSwapHistory" v-on:hide-swap-history="handleHideSwapHistory" v-on:save-json="handleSaveJSON"/>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col>
                        <MyOrders v-bind:myOrders="myOrders" v-bind:myOrdersThisMarket="[]" v-on:refresh-myorders="handleRefreshMyOrders" v-on:cancel-order="handleCancelOrder" v-on:cancel-all-orders="handleCancelAllOrders" ref="myordersref"/>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <!--
        <v-row class="px-4">
          <v-col>
            <NewComponent />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
-->
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-main>
</template>
```

Comment: We've know idea what each custom component contains or what styles are being applied from just the screenshot and given code.  Regardless, the easiest thing is to debug this yourself looking at the DOM inspector to figure out the different heights, paddings, margins, etc. which will tell you what CSS adjustments you need to apply to get things to match.  If you need further help, we'd need a reproducible example to look at.

Comment: The [grid elements](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#sub-components) cannot be stacked arbitrarily.

`v-col` has to be a child of `v-row`, which has to be a child of `v-container`.